# Colocar filtro a una imagen de fondo con css

Tags: html, css

Quiero colocar un filtro a una imagen que pondre de fondo aplicando `background-image:url(url..);` a un `div` pero tengo un problema, el filtro también me esta tomando el contenido que se encuentra dentro de la caja y yo solamente quiero aplicarle el filtro a la imagen y que el contenido, ya sea texto o inputs queden sin el.

Para colocar el filtro solo tome un `<div id="container-fluid-slider>`y a la `id` que le coloque a ese `div` le aplique el filtro `filter:brightness(0.5);` pero como dije anteriormente me esta tomando el contenido dentro de él.

```css
#container-fluid-slider {
  background-image: url(http://www.gelfuzion.com/img/slides/nivo/bg-1.jpg);
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  position: relative;
  filter: brightness(0.5);
}

#container-fluid-slider p {
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#form-slider input {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

#form-slider button {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #268ab9;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div 
  class="container-fluid d-lg-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" 
  id="container-fluid-slider">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 d-lg-flex flex-lg-column " id="col-12-slider">
      <h1 class="text-center">Find Sudan's places number</h1>
      <p class="text-center">Find important numbers such as Hospitals! Pharmacies! Companies etc!</p>
      <div class="line d-lg-flex flex-lg-row" id="form-slider">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Search Number">
        <button class="d-inline ml-3"><i class="fas fa-search text-white pr-3"></i>Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El filtro se aplica a todo el DIV, puedes crear el fondo en un DIV aparte con su filtro, y el contenido en otro DIV encima.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Arnau, puedes utilizar dos `<div>` para aplicar el filtro sólamente al segundo. Para que funcione debes utilizar el **z-index**, que le dice al elemento en qué profundidad debe estar, quedando el div con la imagen de fondo  para poder mostrar el resto de elementos.

Problemas de esta implementación:

- Requiere posicionamiento absoluto de ambos, con misma anchura y altura, si intentas poner anchura/altura = 100% se extenderá hasta el siguiente elemento no estático (la ventana del navegador).

Por lo demás, el `<div>` secundario ignora todo el contenido a la hora de posicionarse y aplicar el filtro.

```css
#row-row
{
z-index:1;
width:300px;
height:300px;
top:0;
left:0;
overflow:hidden;
position: absolute;
color:white;
border: 1px solid red;
}

#fight-the-power{
z-index:-1;
width:300px;
height:300px;
top:0;
left:0;
background-image:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6402bed98d1b9576a4d584e0ff8d61a4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
position:absolute;
filter:brightness(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id='row-row'>
Este texto no está afectado.
  <div id='fight-the-power' ></div>
  <br />
   Ni este input:
   <br />
   Mi super input <input /> 
   <br />
   Ni este botón
   <input type='button' value='Pulsa'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

También se puede aplicar un filtro mediante un gradiente. Ya que para implementar un gradiente se necesita usar la propiedad "backgroun-image" se puede usar esto dentro de la misma linea separada por una coma, como los gradientes son una transición entre dos colores los dos pueden ser negro implementados mediante la función rgba() definiendo la opacidad como un numero entre 0.0 (transparente) y 1.0 (opaco)

```css
.hero {
  height: 45rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
     ),  
     url('../../img/hero.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  margin-top: -12rem;
}
```